# How to substitute a column in a pandas dataframe whit a series?

Tags: pandas

Let's have a dataframe *df* and a series *s1* in pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000,1000))
s1 = pd.Series(range(0,10000))
```

How can I modify *df* so that the column 42 become equal to *s1*?

How can I modify *df* so that the columns between 42 and 442 become equal to *s1*?

I would like to know the simplest way to do that but also a way to do that in place.

Comment: Your series has only 1000 elements while your df has 10000 rows. so how do you expect this to happen?

Comment: Just a typo, now I corrected the question to match the sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need first same length `Series` with `DataFrame`, here `20`:

```
np.random.seed(456)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,10))
#print (df)
s1 = pd.Series(range(0,20))
#print (s1)

#set column by Series
df[8] = s1
#set Series to range of columns
cols = df.loc[:, 3:5].columns
df[cols] = pd.concat([s1] * len(cols), axis=1)
print (df)
           0         1         2   3   4   5         6         7   8         9
0  -0.668129 -0.498210  0.618576   0   0   0  0.301966  0.449483   0 -0.315231
1  -2.015971 -1.130231 -1.111846   1   1   1  1.915676  0.920348   1  1.157552
2  -0.106208 -0.088752 -0.971485   2   2   2 -0.366948 -0.301085   2  1.141635
3  -1.309529 -0.274381  0.864837   3   3   3  0.670294  0.086347   3 -1.212503
4   0.120359 -0.358880  1.199936   4   4   4  0.389167  1.201631   4  0.445432
5  -1.031109  0.067133 -1.213451   5   5   5 -0.636896  0.013802   5  1.726135
6  -0.491877  0.254206 -0.268168   6   6   6  0.671070 -0.633645   6  1.813671
7   0.080433 -0.882443  1.152671   7   7   7  0.249225  1.385407   7  1.010374
8   0.307274  0.806150  0.071719   8   8   8  1.133853 -0.789922   8 -0.286098
9  -0.767206  1.094445  1.603907   9   9   9  0.083149  2.322640   9  0.396845
10 -0.740018 -0.853377 -2.039522  10  10  10  0.764962 -0.472048  10 -0.071255
11 -0.238565  1.077573  2.143252  11  11  11  1.542892  2.572560  11 -0.803516
12 -0.139521 -0.992107 -0.892619  12  12  12  0.259612 -0.661760  12 -1.508976
13 -1.077001  0.381962  0.205388  13  13  13 -0.023986 -1.293080  13  1.846402
14 -0.714792 -0.728496 -0.127079  14  14  14  0.606065 -2.320500  14 -0.992798
15 -0.127113 -0.563313 -0.101387  15  15  15  0.647325 -0.816023  15 -0.309938
16 -1.151304 -1.673719  0.074930  16  16  16 -0.392157  0.736714  16  1.142983
17 -1.247396 -0.471524  1.173713  17  17  17 -0.005391  0.426134  17  0.781832
18 -0.325111  0.579248  0.040363  18  18  18  0.361926  0.036871  18  0.581314
19 -1.057501 -1.814500  0.109628  19  19  19 -1.738658 -0.061883  19  0.989456
```

**Timings**

Another solutions, but it seems `concat` solution is fastest:

```
np.random.seed(456)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,1000))
#print (df)
s1 = pd.Series(range(0,1000))
#print (s1)

#set column by Series
df[8] = s1
#set Series to range of columns
cols = df.loc[:, 42:442].columns
print (df)


In [310]: %timeit df[cols] = np.broadcast_to(s1.values[:, np.newaxis], (len(df),len(cols)))
1 loop, best of 3: 202 ms per loop

In [311]: %timeit df[cols] = np.repeat(s1.values[:, np.newaxis], len(cols), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 208 ms per loop

In [312]: %timeit df[cols] = np.array([s1.values]*len(cols)).transpose()
10 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop

In [313]: %timeit df[cols] = pd.concat([s1] * len(cols), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.8 ms per loop
```